# Security defaults is not working for user created by Azure AD graph API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

We have Azure Active Directory with Security Default enabled. We have the MVC application which is creating the users in the Azure active directory using graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

When I logged in the first time using a newly created user into the azure portal, it asked for more information to set up the Microsoft Authenticator app on my phone. I set up an account in the authenticator app successfully. When I tried to sign in again after sign out, it supposes to send me a notification on phone for approval. But portal allowed me to sign in without MFA verification.

The Security Default setting is not working as expected when the user is created using graph API tried to login into the MVC application. It is working fine when I tried to login into the portal.azure.com.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: The documentation link attached uses Microsoft Graph and the tag here is azure-ad-graph-api. If you are actually using MS Gra0ph, I have tested and I don't see that behavior. Did you test from a different ip or in private mode?

Comment: Sorry I mentioned the wrong tag. Yes, I am using MS Graph API. I tried private mode also but the MVC application is directly allowing me to sign in without MFA verification. Is there any setting need to do in Azure app registration to allow MFA for SSO?

Comment: Is the security policy for MFA enforced on the portal? This is under Home > Azure Active Directory > Identity Protection > MFA Policy. At the bottom enforce policy should  be on.

Comment: I am not able to find the Identity Protection option under Azure Active Directory. Instead of that, I have Identity Governance option. Is it requires a Premium subscription?

Comment: The Full path is Azure Portal > AAD > Security > Identity Protection > MFA Policy. What is the AAD plan your tenant has?

Comment: This setting page is showing me 'This view is for Azure AD Premium P2 customers to setup MFA registration policy. Other customers can only disable policies here.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235055/discussion-between-v-mulik-and-danstan).